# how to elegantly parse argumens in python before expensive imports?

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script, which parses a few arguments, and has some expensive imports, but those imports are only needed if the user gives valid input arguments, otherwise the program exits. Also, when the user says `python script.py --help`, there is no need for those expensive imports to be executed at all.

I can think of such a script:

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--argument', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()

import gensim # expensive import
import blahblahblah

def the_rest_of_the_code(args):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_rest_of_the_code(args)
```

This does the job, but it doesn't look elegant to me. Any better suggestions for the task?

**EDIT**: the import is really expensive:

```
$ time python -c "import gensim"
Using TensorFlow backend.

real    0m12.257s
user    0m10.756s
sys 0m0.348s
```

Comment: Put it in another module.

Comment: Also, why is the import expensive?

Comment: It loads tensorflow, and runs a bunch of code to prepare its NLP modules.

Comment: Everything following a `if __name__` should be indented.

Comment: @Elazar I think he meant by expensive some import modules take a long time to be imported

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can import conditionally, or in a `try` block, or just about anywhere in code.

So you could do something like this:

```
import cheaplib

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()
    if expensive_arg in args:
        import expensivelib
    do_stuff(args)
```

Or even more clearly, only import the lib in the function that will use it.

```
def expensive_function():
    import expensivelib
    ...
```

Comment: Better than my answer

Comment: So in arguments we should provide the name of the `expensivelib` name?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it's better than what you already have, but you can load it lazily:

```
def load_gensim():
    global gensim
    import gensim
```

If you only want to make sure the arguments make sense, you can have a wrapper `main` module that checks the arguments and then loads another module and call it.

main.py:

```
args = check_args()
if args is not None:
    import mymodule
    mymodule.main(args)
```

mymodule.py:

```
import gensim
def main(args):
    # do work
```